# Animal Crossing New Leaf boat is gone

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I loaded custom firmware on my 3DS and used it to rebuild my ACNL city exactly like my old one. Everything works fine, but the boat is gone. Is there a way to get it back or can I just never again visit the island?